# Finding domain where inverse function exists

Tags: functions

For the function with the rule:

$$f: B \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, f(x) = 4x^3 + 3x^2 +1$$

For what domain, will an inverse function exist?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$f'(x)=12x^2+6x=6x(2x+1)$$
so we can see that $f$ is continous and strictly increasing on the intervals $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2})$ and $(0,+\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on the interval $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ so in each these intervals an inverse function of $f$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

The following result is useful

> A function has an inverse if and only if it is bijective

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just for some and not all posibilities. Then you just check if the first derivative is unequal $0$, then in a small neighbourhood there exists an inverse function.